# Python 2.7 Recursive call on formatting dictionary key property

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sample dictionary data.

```
obj = {  
    "company-name":"Name Test",
    "contact-name":"Test contact",
    "contact-phone":"1234567890",
    "contact-email":"test@example.com",
    "contact-notes":"Test Notes",
    "company-clients": {
        "client-name": "Test Client",
        "client-address": "Test Client address",
        "client-occupation": {
            "occupation-title": "Test occupation title",
            "occupation-salary": 600000
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need it to format all the property with a `-` and replace it with `_` instead so. This is the desireable output:

```
{  
    "company_name":"Name Test",
    "contact_name":"Test contact",
    "contact_phone":"1234567890",
    "contact_email":"test@example.com",
    "contact_notes":"Test Notes",
    "company_clients": {
        "client_name": "Test Client",
        "client_address": "Test Client address",
        "client_occupation": {
            "occupation_title": "Test occupation title",
            "occupation_salary": 600000
        }
    }
}
```

So far here is what i tried:

```
def recursive_formatting(key, value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        return key.replace('-', '_'), value
    else:
        for k, v in value.items():
            _k, _v = recursive_formatting(k, v)
            return _k, _v
```

**USAGE**

```
data = {}
for key, value in obj.items():
    k, v = recursive_formatting(key, value)
    data[k] = v

print data
```

But the code doesn't do a nested formatting only at the root level of the object properties is formatted/changed.

This is what i get:

```
{  
    "company_name":"Name Test",
    "contact_name":"Test contact",
    "contact_phone":"1234567890",
    "contact_email":"test@example.com",
    "contact_notes":"Test Notes"
}
```

Comment: Do you expect that `-` characters might exist in the values?

Comment: @ScottMcC Nope, only in the `key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a generator based solution is probably easiest to read

```
def converter(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        k = k.replace('-', '_')
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield k, dict(converter(v))
        else:
            yield k, v

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict(converter(obj)))
```

prints

```
{'company_clients': {'client_address': 'Test Client address',
                     'client_name': 'Test Client',
                     'client_occupation': {'occupation_salary': 600000,
                                           'occupation_title': 'Test occupation title'}},
 'company_name': 'Name Test',
 'contact_email': 'test@example.com',
 'contact_name': 'Test contact',
 'contact_notes': 'Test Notes',
 'contact_phone': '1234567890'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect that `-` might exist in the values, a quick hack could involve dumping the `obj` to `json` and replacing all values of `-` with `_`

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = {  
...     "company-name":"Name Test",
...     "contact-name":"Test contact",
...     "contact-phone":"1234567890",
...     "contact-email":"test@example.com",
...     "contact-notes":"Test Notes",
...     "company-clients": {
...         "client-name": "Test Client",
...         "client-address": "Test Client address",
...         "client-occupation": {
...             "occupation-title": "Test occupation title",
...             "occupation-salary": 600000
...         }
...     }
... }

>>> new_obj = json.loads(json.dumps(obj).replace("-", "_"))
>>> new_obj
{'company_clients': {'client_address': 'Test Client address',
                     'client_name': 'Test Client',
                     'client_occupation': {'occupation_salary': 600000,
                                           'occupation_title': 'Test '
                                                               'occupation '
                                                               'title'}},
 'company_name': 'Name Test',
 'contact_email': 'test@example.com',
 'contact_name': 'Test contact',
 'contact_notes': 'Test Notes',
 'contact_phone': '1234567890'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a recursive function which takes the initial dictionary as it's argument by using dictionary comprehensions.

Note, this will return a new dictionary instead of mutating one in place.

```
def recursive_format(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {key.replace('-', '_'): recursive_format(value) 
                for key, value in obj.items()}
    return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
def rep(d, _new = ['-', '_']):
  return {a.replace(*_new):b if not isinstance(b, dict) else rep(b) for a, b in d.items()}

print(rep(obj))
```

Output:

```
{'company_name': 'Name Test', 'contact_name': 'Test contact', 'contact_phone': '1234567890', 'contact_email': 'test@example.com', 'contact_notes': 'Test Notes', 'company_clients': {'client_name': 'Test Client', 'client_address': 'Test Client address', 'client_occupation': {'occupation_title': 'Test occupation title', 'occupation_salary': 600000}}}
```

Comment: Why a list instead of a tuple for `_new`?